# PF10 Theme Avalon 3 Is there an alternative to ui-inputgroup without <p:separator/>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, themes

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11
- Primefaces 10
- Avalon 3.0.0 migration from 2.1.2

Is there an alternative to ui-inputgroup without <p:separator/>?

Following the migration instructions from PF10 we replace <p:separator/> by <p:divider/> I am having problems with design of ui-inputgroup.

[image]

**Code Example**

```
<div class="ui-inputgroup">
    <p:inputText id="txtId" value="#{menusBean.search.id}" style="width:50%"/>
    <p:divider/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cbxContext"
                     value="#{menusBean.search.context}"
                     filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                     autoWidth="false" style="width:50%">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{menusBean.loadParesN1Search}" update="cbxPare"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="BACK" itemValue="BACK"/>
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="EXTRA" itemValue="EXTRA"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</div>
```

I didn't find this option in Avalon demo v3.0.0, so I guess should be an alternative to this.

By testing alternatives I tried to replace back <p:divider/> by <p:separator/> and it works but it will be deprecated before long.

[image]

Comment: Why not use custom styling instead of a component?

Comment: I am migrating an app I thought would be easier, but the best option would be no frameworks no migrations, use standars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set a right border on your input:

```html
<div class="ui-inputgroup">
    <p:inputText style="width:50%;border-right:1px solid #ced4da"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu autoWidth="false" style="width:50%">
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</div>
```

Which will render like:

[image]